# Пример того как изменяется контекст во время выполнения XPath запроса

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

Может кто-нибудь объяснить пошагово как изменяется контекст при выполнении **XPath** выражения? Особенно интересует как вычисляется **СontextPosition** и **ContextSize**. Есть такой запрос: **//item[2]**.

Выполняется на таком документе:

```
<root>
  <node>
    <item/>
    <item/>
    <item/>
  </node>
  <item/>
  <node>
    <item/>
    <item/>
    <item/>
  </node>
  <item/>
</root>
```

Не могу понять как вычисляется позиция элемента во время выполнения.

Comment: не совсем понятно, о чём вопрос... `//item[2]` просто выводит второй элемент `item`. в данном случае  это три элемента: в каждом `node`, а также один в `root`...

Comment: В стандарте описано как выполняется XPath выражение. Каждый шаг выражения создает новый node-set, элементы которого передаются в качестве контекстных при выполнении следующего шага. У нас есть предикат: [2] ~ [position()=2]. Свойство контекстного элемента, такое как position(), равно позиции этого элемента в node-set. Но когда я пытаюсь расписать для каждого шага получаемый node-set, то выбираться по идее должны другие элементы. Вот я и хотел чтобы мне пошагово объяснили как получаются эти node-set'ы.

Comment: Что вы используете для выполнения XPath? Я знаю о возможности дебагинга XSLT (а следовательно и XPath) в Visual Studio Enterprise - нет ли у вас к ней доступа? Там можно пошагово проходить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Чтобы было легче понимать, о каких именно элементах речь, изменим xml следующим образом:

```
<root>  
  <node>
    <item>1</item>
    <item>2</item>
    <item>3</item>
  </node>
  <item>4</item>  
  <node>
    <item>5</item>
    <item>6</item>
    <item>7</item>
  </node>
  <item>8</item>  
</root>
```

Путь `//` проходит по всем узлам. Если точкой отсчёта является корень xml, то элементы со значениями 1, 2, 3 составят первый node-set. Вторым элементом `[2]` будет 2.
Второй node-set - элементы со значениями 5, 6, 7. Второй элемент среди них: 6.
Элементы со значениями 4 и 8 образуют ещё один node-set. Номер `[2]` - это 8.